# How can I write a matching regexp for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, string, match

I am looking for the keyword `"admin"` in this array :

```
params[:controller] = ["admin","organizations"]
```

So I wrote this :

```
params[:controller].split(/\//).each{|a|a.match(/admin/)}
```

But this puzzlingly returns :

```
["admin", "organizations"]
```

What correct syntax am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use

```
params[:controller].include? "admin"
```

Comment: Definitely (assuming normalized strings; I didn't, based on the original regex nature of the question, although since it's looking at the controller hierarchy, I bet you're right so +1)

Answer (score 1):

`each` returns the original array.

It sounds more like [you want `any?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/any?), which returns `true` if any collection element gets a truthy value returned from the block.

(You could always just `join`, too.)

Answer (score 0):

Your match statement is not really doing anything, since it produces no output. If you had `puts a.match(/admin/)`, it would write "admin" out once.

The actual return value of each is the array, which is why you are seeing the original array being returned..